# Azure App Service ERROR: Container test-xx_0_xxxxxxxx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

Django web app works fine in local development environment, after deploying it to Azure App Service using:

```
az webapp up --resource-group test --location australiaeast --plan test-plan-01 --sku B1 --name test-app-01 --runtime PYTHON:3.10
```

it ends with error:

```
2023-07-04T05:25:29.544Z ERROR - Container test-xxxx_0_xxxxxxxx for site test-app-01 has exited, failing site start

2023-07-04T05:25:29.606Z ERROR - Container test-xxxx_0_xxxxxxxx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

2023-07-04T05:25:29.612Z INFO  - Stopping site test-app-01 because it failed during startup.*
```

===================================

Update:

I was using [WhiteNoise](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) hosting static files, after removing `STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"` from settings.py the deployment went well.

Comment: Please add more information than just "I did a thing and it doesn't work". We need some more (relevant) information to be able to help you, like a Docker file or some configuration.
On topic: your "Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port 8000". Does your Docker file specify that port number as `EXPOSE` and is it connected to the correct service? Please use setting `WEBSITES_PORT` to specify the correct port number your container is listening on.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure App Service ERROR:  Didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging:-

According to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=django,windows,azure-cli,azure-cli-deploy,deploy-instructions-azportal,terminal-bash,deploy-instructions-zip-azcli), I tried to run the same command as you once I ran django app locally and it worked as expected.

[image]

***Running successfully in a local environment:***

[image]

***After that, I ran*** `az webapp up` ***to create and deploy web app resources as follows:***

```bash
az webapp up --runtime PYTHON:3.10 --sku <SKU> --logs
```

[image]

***Launched app Url successfully after deployment:***

[image]

***Alternatively,***

It is possible that the port number in your `Django` app is incorrectly specified. Define the port number to your Django app's `settings.py` file as follows.

Use `os.environ` method to specify the unused port number to run the `django` app as shown.

```bash
import os 
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', <portnum(Eg:5000)>))
```

***Then run server command would be in the below format.***

```bash
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORTNUMBER
```

**Note:** *After making the above changes, try deploying your code again and check it.* You can also use [`az webapp log tail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-log-tail) to check the live tracing logs of the deploying webapp.

Refer [MSDoc](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/AzWebAppUP/runtime_detection.md#python-detection-logic) for more ways of resolving the above issue.

Comment: did you use `DEBUG = False` or `DEBUG = True` when deploying to Azure? When I using `DEBUG = False` it would end with container start failure, otherwise no issue the container starts.

Comment: I did not use either of the above but it worked. @J.W

Comment: I mean in Django project folder settings.py, there is a setting for DEBUG, if you removed the DEBUG from settings, then by default it's using False: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-DEBUG

Comment: In the quick start project you download from Github, the DEBUG is True: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart/blob/main/quickstartproject/settings.py

Comment: I would suggest you turn on the debug mode all times. It displays all the error messages and live tracking errors in a detailed way and it will be easy to identify the issue quickly. Check here for the django [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/) for better understanding.

Comment: the problem was, when using `DEBUG = True` the deployed container started without issue, when using `DEBUG = False` the container failed to start most of the time, but sometimes it worked, so not sure if this was an Azure side issue or not.

Comment: This might be a backend issue and not related to the command or any.

Comment: you are right, I found the issue linked to WhiteNoise, after removing `STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"` from settings.py the deploying went well. thank you

Comment: @SPT the above answer didn't really solve the problem, the problem was solved after removing `STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"`, not sure if accept this answer would confuse other people

Comment: Apart from the backend issue, the above given procedure for your requirement is correct and port issue will be resolved if you switch to another port.